Calculate a light enough shade of a given color to use as background for black text
Suppose my web app is given any random color, say purple, to use as a base accent color.
Black - or nearly black - text has a bad contrast against this purple background:

But if you make background a very very light shade of purple, it will be ok for reading and still retain some purpleness to be consistent with the base purple color:

How to automatically calculate that new color for any given base color (in JavaScript / SCSS)?

modern browsers you can use something like background-color: oklab(from purple 95% a b); - which increases the brightness of the "base" colour - also background-color: oklch(from purple 95% c h); there's also lab, lch and hsl - they produce slightly different results - this is vanilla CSS, no libraries required

I just thought of a good easy idea, you could probably just put an 80~90% opacity white div (using :before and position: absolute) over a div containing just your background colour and that would technically both lighten and desaturate the background colour like you want. Most browsers should do their rendering in linear RGB so it should work well with any color. Skips messing around with colour spaces.

@MikhailBatcer Are you okay with an Answer that uses RGB values (instead of CSS colours like "purple")?

Modern browsers allow you to create a color "from" another colour

Note: Firefox was the last (major) browser to implement this in the latest version (128) released just 10 days ago - it's not yet released on Android though which is apparently still on version 127.


I just checked my Android phone, and Firefox 128 HAS been released - seems caniuse.com is not bleeding edge up to date (it NEVER is for Firefox in general anyway)

For example
hsl(from purple h s 95%); - docs
takes purple and adjusts just the lightness keeping hue and saturation untouched
similar results can be gotten using lab, oklab, lch and oklch
Here's the results using all of the above - I've used 95% for lightness in each case - which seems to produce a good enough result
You can however use calc() and maybe min() to refine the effect further


body {
  color: black;
  font-size: 28px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div {
  min-width:50%;
}
.original {
  background-color: purple;
}
.oklab {
  background-color: oklab(from purple 95% a b);
}
.lab {
  background-color: lab(from purple 95% a b);
}
.oklch {
  background-color: oklch(from purple 95% c h);
}
.lch {
  background-color: lch(from purple 95% c h);
}
.hsl {
  background-color: hsl(from purple h s 95%);
}
.light {
  background-color: hsl(from yellow h s max(80, l))
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow
}
.purple {
  background-color: purple
}
.lpurple {
  background-color: hsl(from purple h s max(80, l))
}
<div class="original">Hello original</div>
<div class="hsl">Hello HSL</div>
<div class="oklab">Hello OKLAB</div>
<div class="lab">Hello LAB</div>
<div class="oklch">Hello OKLCH</div>
<div class="lch">Hello LCH</div>
<div class="yellow">Hello LIGHT</div>
<div class="light">Hello LIGHT</div>
<div class="purple">Hello DARK</div>
<div class="lpurple">Hello DARK</div>



The relative colours are very interesting to use in general - you can use other colour spaces as the from colour. So, if you already have a bunch of colours defined but you want to change them using a different colour model, you can.
e.g.
hsl(from rgb(255, 0, 255) h s 95%)
rgb(from #ff00ff b r g) 


Thanks! The problem is how to calculate that it should be "95 %" for the given background color. Maybe the given color already has a very light hue? or maybe not? the calculation should be automatic.

I've added some more examples @MikhailBatcer - you can play with calc max min as you see fit - there's going to be a way

The APCA contrast calculator is perceptually uniform and is useful for dark color pairs. You can access it at https://apcacontrast.com and here's a link to a specific example that answers your question:
#111 on #d296ff
Also, the apca-w3 npm package does have a "reverse APCA" function, though the color it returns is grayscale. A color version will be released as part of the SACAM color space.
In the interim, using binary search while increasing luminance (and potentially reducing saturation) using OKLch or HSLuv, until a given Lc value is obtained (such as Lc 60 or Lc 75).
I happen to like the quasi-uniform CIELUV, and a useful implementation is HSLuv.org. Using this, adjust L to increase the Lc value. Unlike many other controls (especially the non-uniform HSL and HSV etc), in HSLuv, the L control gives you the complete range from #000 to #fff, and remembers/maintains hue and saturation (to the degree possible) across the range.
Edits to Add:
There are posts in this thread mentioning HSV and other non-uniform methods. These methods should not be used calculating contrast, as they will give unpredictable (or undesired) results.
There is even a problem with OKLch and HSLuv, in that they use some variant of L* (Lstar) which indicates middle contrast at half the luminance it should, resulting in dark color pair problems.
APCA is based around modern color models such as CIECAM02, CAM16, R-LAB, and other research. It places the midrange more accurately. It is possible to use APCA in conjunction with either OKLch or HSLuv, in a two step process separating the Lc value calcuation.
MidPoint
Since the idea here is flipping between black and white (or selecting BGs that work with one or the other), this can be simplified by making the flip point at a L* value of ~66.
This is a luminance value of 36 Y.
